# does android sdk give any convenience methods for converting Shape to Path?

Tags: java, android

the Canvas class does not take Shape as a parameter for any of its methods.  There is no drawShape or clipShape, etc...  So, I need to use Path instead.  Does android sdk expose any way to convert Shape to Path or Path to shape?  I haven't been able to find relationship any between the 2 classes...?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape is just an abstraction over the Canvas. It may or may not use a Path internally. You cannot convert a Shape to a Path directly, but all Shapes can be implemented using Path. You can however create a Shape from a Path using the PathShape class.